# SQL to generate fantasy league schedule

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out the best way to tackle this and I'm having some trouble...What I want to do is write a SQL script to generate a head-to-head schedule for a league that could have a variable (but known beforehand) number of teams and a variable (but known beforehand) number of weeks.

I have a schema like the following (simplified for the sake of the question here)

### Table: Teams

```
team_id   int
team_name varchar(50)
```

### Table: FantasyWeeks

```
week_id    int
start_date datetime
end_date   datetime
```

### Table: FantasyMatches

```
match_id      int
home_team_id  int
away_team_id  int
week_id       int  (FK FantasyWeeks.week_id)
```

So for example, if there were 6 teams (so 3 matches a week) and 12 weeks, there would end up being 36 matches generated with each team playing the other teams at least twice and playing 2 other teams 3 times - which team was 'away' and 'home' would need to alternate.

I've tried doing some stuff with CROSS JOINs and CURSORs but it hasn't produced the desired results yet. Any ideas? I'm sure I could handle this in C# no problem but I'd like to do it in the database using SQL if possible.

```
EDIT: Here is a sample schedule for week 1:

Home Team: Team 1 vs. Away Team: Team 2
Home Team: Team 3 vs. Away Team: Team 4
Home Team: Team 5 vs. Away Team: Team 6

Week 2 would be something like this:

Home Team: Team 1 vs. Away Team: Team 3
Home Team: Team 2 vs. Away Team: Team 5
Home Team: Team 4 vs. Away Team: Team 6
```

Comment: Can you post your `CROSS JOIN` and `CURSOR` stuff here, so understand what you are trying to do better?

Comment: One should note that with six teams, alternating Home/Away for every team would mean that some matches have two home teams, and some have two away teams.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are quite a few possibilities how such a schedule could look like, you would have to think of a generalized schedule first. If you have one (as indicated by that you could write the program in C#), you should post it here.

Of course you could write a STORED PROCEDURE, because this is what they are there for in the first place. I don't think that it can be done with simple SQL query.